# WordPress CPT register_post_type() Row Actions Disappeared

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to set up a custom post type with limited row actions (Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View); I just want Trash and View. Extra points if we can put View before Trash. But at this point they've all disappeared, and I can only make them come back when I remove the `capabilities` sub-array.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
register_post_type('WEBSITES', [
    'menu_icon'                 => 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet',
    'menu_position'             => 5,   // below Posts
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'publicly_queryable'        => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'         => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar'         => false,
    'hierarchical'              => false,
    'supports'                  => [],
    'show_ui'                   => true,
    'show_in_menu'              => true,
    'labels'                    => [
        'name'                      => 'Websites',
        'singular_name'             => 'Website',
        'add_new_item'              => 'Add New Website',
        'view_item'                 => 'View Website Source',
        'all_items'                 => 'All Websites',
        'search_items'              => 'Search Websites',
    ],
    'capabilities'              => [ 
        'create_posts'              => false,
        'edit_post'                 => true,
        'read_post'                 => true,
        'delete_post'               => true,
        'edit_posts'                => true,
        'edit_others_posts'         => true,
    ],
    'register_meta_box_cb'      => [$this, 'showMetaBox'],
]);
```

So, how do I allow View and Trash in the actions row?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the optimal way to handle this, but I removed the `capabilities` sub-array, and added the `post_row_actions` filter, where I added the View entry:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', [$this, 'filterRowActions'], 10, 2);
```

Then:

```
public function filterRowActions($actions, $post) {
    $actions['view'] = "<a href=\"http://localhost/wp-admin/post.php?post={$post->ID}&amp;action=edit\" aria-label=\"View \“{$post->post_title}\”\">View</a>";
    return $actions;
}
```

That works. Feel free to let me know if there are better ways of achieving this.

Comment: Hint: You're doing that for a custom post type, so I suggest you to check if the filter is being applied on a standard `post_type` or a custom `post_type`. Here's an [example](https://pastebin.com/xKBZDsCH). This way, you can also have only "Trash" and "View" actions, and the "View" being the first action (unless of course filtered by plugins).